# SSIS Derived Column - expression to retrieve date from Filename

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I have a file name "Asia Marine Workbook - Oct 2017.xlsx" coming through every month. I need a create two columns with Derived Columns 'month' and 'year' that should output as integers like 09 and 2017 from the filename..

Any suggestions or thoughts would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like until now you didn't get you informed badge, feel free to take the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about asking questions, accepting answers, upvoting and other stackoverflow features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming that `@[User::FilePath]` is a variable that contains the following value `Asia Marine Workbook - Oct 2017.xlsx`*

***1. To get the Year value you can use the following expression***

```
(DT_I4)LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],9),4)
```

*Result*

> 2017

***2. To get the month String value you can use the following***

```
LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),3)
```

*Result*

> Oct

***3. To get the month in Integer value***

```
(DT_I4)(UPPER(LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),3)) == "JAN" ? "01" :
UPPER(LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),3)) == "FEB" ? "02" : 
UPPER(LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),3)) == "MAR" ? "03" :
UPPER(LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),3)) == "APR" ? "04" :
UPPER(LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),3)) == "MAY" ? "05" : 
UPPER(LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),3)) == "JUN" ? "06" :
UPPER(LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),3)) == "JUL" ? "07" :
UPPER(LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),3)) == "AUG" ? "08" :
UPPER(LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),3)) == "SEP" ? "09" : 
UPPER(LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),3)) == "OCT" ? "10" : 
UPPER(LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),3)) == "NOV" ? "11" : 
UPPER(LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),3)) == "DEC"? "12":"")
```

*Result*

> 10

*Or convert concatenate the date with a day value and convert it to `(DT_DATE)` then extract the month value*

```
MONTH((DT_DATE)"1 " + LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),8))
```

*Result*

> 10

*Also if you need to return it as string with 2 digits (i.e 01)*

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,10)MONTH((DT_DATE)"1 " + LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),8)),2)
```

*Result*

> 10

Answer (score 0):

The following expressions will get you what you're looking for.

**YEAR**

String:

```
SUBSTRING([ColumnName], 28, 4)
```

Integer:

```
(DT_I4) SUBSTRING([ColumnName], 28, 4)
```

**MONTH**

String:

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH((DT_DATE) ("1 " + SUBSTRING([ColumnName], 24, 3) + " 2017")), 2)
```

Integer:

```
MONTH((DT_DATE) ("1 " + SUBSTRING([ColumnName], 24, 3) + " 2017"))
```

*Note: "09" is not an integer, it would have to be a `string`.*

Comment: getting this error "[Derived Column [40]] Error: Error code 0x80020005 occurred attempting to convert from data type DT_WSTR to data type DT_DATE."

Comment: I tried this "RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH((DT_DATE)("1 " + SUBSTRING(@[User::FilePath],24,3) + " 2017")),2)" and returned the above error

Comment: What is the value in `@[User::FilePath]`? What does the following expression return: `SUBSTRING(@[User::FilePath], 24, 3)`?

Comment: @ChrisMack all your expressions are working fine, but i think if the filename  is formatted this way `XXXXXX MMM YYYY.xlsx` it is better to read from the end of the string for 2 reasons: 1) if the variable contains the file full path it will still working 2) if the prefix (`Asia Marine...`) changes it will work also.

Comment: @ChrisMack however you have a working solution based on the OP inputs, and i think that your effort must be appreciated +1

Comment: @ChrisMack using `SUBSTRING` is not recommended at all

Comment: @Yahfoufi Why not? And according to who? If it's "not recommended at all", why does it exist?

Comment: @ChrisMack when the filename changes this will not be working, if the filename is `Europe Marine Workbook - Oct 2017.xlsx` as example. It is better to read from the end because the length of `Oct 2017.xlsx` will not change cause has the format `MMM YYYY.xlsx`

Comment: @Yahfoufi I'm well aware of that, but did the OP specify that there would be variety of filenames? No. What if the filename were `Asia Marine Workbook - Oct 2017 v2.xlsx`. Then my solution would still work, and yours would not. What you are saying is highly presumptive (the OP provided no detail on a variety in filenames), and your criticism of my solution is therefore decidedly illegitimate.